# Get contact fields from Opportunity

Tags: soql

How can I get a Contact from the Account while querying Opportunity?

```
SELECT o.Id, o.AccountId, a.Name
FROM Opportunity o, o.Account a
```

I can get all fields from Opportunity, account.Name. But how to include contact fields (email) that are inside the Account?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest just breaking this into two queries. One to get the list of `Account` Ids given some `Opportunity` records, and then another one to query for `Contacts` based on the `Account` Ids.

If this query is inside of an `Opportunity` trigger, it'd only require one query (you'd have access to `Opportunity.AccountId` through one of the trigger context variables).

```
[SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN : <list of Account Ids>]
```

You could also use a parent-child subquery. If you store the result of this query in a `Map<Id, Account>`, you would have easy access to the `Contacts`

```
Map<Id, Account> accountWithContacts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : <list of Account Ids>]);
List<Contact> oppContacts = accountWithContacts.get(opportunity.AccountId).get('Contacts');
```

**+edit:**

After second thought, the method below wouldn't really help save any queries in any situation. If you're outside of an `Opporunity` trigger, you'd likely need a query to get the `Account` Ids, and if you were, including the parent-child subquery to `Opportunity` would be useless.

**/edit**

If you do need to keep your number of queries down, then it might be worth it to explore refactoring so your main query is on `Account`, using that as a junction table to tie `Opportunity` and `Contact` together.

```
[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, email FROM Contacts), (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : <list of Account Ids you get from Opportunities>]
```

This query would count as 1 SOQL query, with 2 'Aggregate' queries. The transaction limit for these 'Aggregate' queries is currently 300, vs 100 for normal SOQL queries. All of the rows queried from `Account`, `Contact`, and `Opportunity` will (individually) count against the 50,000 limit.